# If A is a linear operator and x= v, x = cv are both solutions, what can be said about b?

Tags: linear-algebra

If A is a linear operator and both x = v and x = cv (for any real
number c) are solutions to Ax = b, then what can you say about b?

Can we say b = cb, because x = v is really x = cv (where c = 1), making cA(x) = cb?

A(x) = b 
A(v) = b
cA(v) = cb
A(cv) = cb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

For any $c\in\mathbb{R}$ you have

$$b\underbrace{=}_{cv\:\mathrm{solution}\:\mathrm{of}\: Ax=b}A(cv)\underbrace{=}_{\mathrm{linearity}}cA(v) \underbrace{=}_{v\:\mathrm{solution}\:\mathrm{of}\: Ax=b}cb\implies \cdots$$

Comment: Can we say b = cb, because x = v is really x = cv (where c = 1), making A(x) = b?

A(x) = b
A(v) = b
cA(v) = cb
A(cv) = cb

Comment: What can you infer from $b=cb$ for $c\ne 1?$

Comment: I can infer that b ≠ bc  if c≠ {1,0}

Comment: Write $b=cb$ as $(1-c)b=0.$ If $c\ne 1$ then $1-c\ne 0.$ So $b$ is ...

Comment: inconsistent? (Perhaps it might help to give me a list of possible answers so I can understand what choices do I have to describe b.)

Comment: If you multiply a scalar and a vector and the result is the zero vector then the first vector must be zero. That is, $b=cb$ with $c\ne 1$ implies $b=0.$